# deploing django app to heroku: application error

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my project to heroku. I'm new to django and heroku so I'd appreciate any help. All went smoothly up until opening the heroku app with the application error

procfile

```
web: gunicorn count_project.wsgi
```

requirements.txt

```
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.2
django-heroku==0.3.1
gunicorn==19.9.0
psycopg2==2.8.3
pytz==2019.1
sqlparse==0.3.0
whitenoise==4.1.3
```

runtime.txt

```
python-3.7.3
```

message after running heroku logs --tail

```
2019-07-30T13:03:42.277475+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn count_project.wsgi`
2019-07-30T13:03:46.087651+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-07-30T13:03:46.065132+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2019-07-30T13:03:46.018957+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2019-07-30T13:03:46.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-07-30T13:03:58.852793+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=countthewords.herokuapp.com request_id=77fd8632-f1ec-4f12-9271-3f9c42dc19d3 fwd="95.102.233.42" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-07-30T13:04:00.698445+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=countthewords.herokuapp.com request_id=f05da2fd-0222-4ef6-a005-b4dcbd0993ce fwd="95.102.233.42" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Do you also have a `Pipfile` and / or `Pipfile.lock`?

Answer (score -1):

Do you have a buildpack added in Heroku (under settings)?

You should add heroku/python.

Comment: under which settings? sorry for such stupid question this is my first time working with heroku

Comment: In Heroku, go to your project, then the Settings tab. Should be something like https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/YOUR_APP/settings

Comment: And you've redeployed?

Comment: Can you show the logs for the build? (Go to the Activity Tab and click View Build Log beside the latest build)

Comment: This is the log content: 2019-07-30T15:11:56.167929+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/" host=countmywords.herokuapp.com request_id=81045c99-8dbf-4554-b7ee-37a2e92d7932 fwd="95.102.233.42" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https

Comment: I don't know why so many people think they need to set a buildpack manually. In most cases, if you only need a single buildpack, that _isn't necessary_. Buildpacks are inferred from the presence of certain files (like `requirements.txt` for Python).